# using $.post has character limits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I am using jquery $.post method to send a string to a servlet.

```
var temp = "hsad d jad a....sad";
var str="testServlet?param="+temp;
$.post(str, function(data) {
    alert("saved");
});
```

testServlet receives a call when the `temp` has less characters, say 5000. But when it has more no. of characters i.e. > 5000 it is not called. Firebug says 'Aborted'.
I could not understand why.

I thought that this might be because the above code is sending `temp` in the `get` form so I wrote like this -

```
var temp = "hsad d jad a....sad";
var str="testServlet";
$.post(str, {param:temp}, function(data) {
    alert("saved");
});
```

But in this case the servlet was called but param was null.
1. Is there any difference between the above two methods ?
2. If first method is get then why jquery has $.get ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limitations on maximum URL length, depends on  web browser, webserver e.t.c.
When your pass some parameters in url will have problem with too long parameters even if your use POST request.

In your code only **{param:temp}** will be stored in request body. **str** is url so it's has max length restriction.

Comment: So can second method will send any number of characters to the servlet?

Comment: {"yes":"i can send veeery long string here", "not":"any, of corse", "but":"veery long"}

Comment: Yes, it can send them in it' second parameter. Jus't dont put your data in url string.

Comment: HI. Please check this related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680630/sending-long-strings-in-jquery-post
Can you please help me.