# sending long strings in jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I am not able to send long strings (more than 96 char. Tested in FF12 and Chrome 18) in jquery post method.
My servlet is -

```
public class TestServletAsh extends HttpServlet{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(req, resp);
        String xml=req.getParameter("xml");
    }
}
```

and my jquery post request is -

```
<body>
<script>
    function callMe() {
        var str = "dkghjkdf dfg jdfgjd gkdfgdjk gdf gdfg dkjgdfjk gdjgdfjg dfjkgdfjkg dfjkgdfjkg dfjkgdf jkdfgdjhgs";
        $.post(
            "TestServletAsh",
            { xml:str },
            function(data) {
                alert("mission successfull");   //nothing to do with it or data here in this SO question
            }
        );
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="callMe()">Click to send request</a>
</body>
```

I am debugging the servlet and I find "xml=null". I am using jboss as a webserver.
Can anyone please tell me where is the problem.

When I use another version of jquery.post like this -

```
$.post(
    "TestServletAsh?xml="+str,
    function(data) {
        alert("mission successfull");   //nothing to do with it or data here in this SO question
    }
);
```

Then I am able to send around 6000 characters. For more than 6000 characters Firebug says - "405 Aborted". Why ?? Any idea ?

Comment: @Andreas - Please check the last part of the question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your webserver i.e. Jboss could be the issue.
You can look into changing server config parameters

Try setting maxPostSize = 0 in conf/server.xml file