# which method of jquery ajax should I use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, post

I want to send a very long string to a servlet. Could be more than 10,000 characters.

I want to know which jquery ajax/ or any way to send it to the servlet.

I have used $.post and faced characters limit problems.
[sending long strings in jquery post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680630/sending-long-strings-in-jquery-post)
[using $.post has character limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634712/using-post-has-character-limits)

Comment: So why you're posting the same question at the third time? Does your servlet work with an ordinary post form (non-ajax)?

Comment: I regularly do AJAX posts much larger than 10,000 characters without any problems.
Could you please post an example or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem you are seeing?

Comment: I am facing problems in creating a fiddle. I have no idea how one can send servlet request in jsfiddle. Where do we keep a servlet.

Comment: @thg435 - there is possible problems in the servlet. I tried an ordinary form post and it is not accepting more than 96 characters. Is there a problem with my webserver ?

Comment: @MotaBOS: if it doesn't work with a simple form, yes, I guess the problem is on the server side. Check error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there is any doubt left in your mind here:

```
function ajaxTest () {
    var longstr = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

    while (true) {
        longstr += longstr;
        if (longstr.length > 100000) {
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(longstr.length);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax',
        type: 'post',
        data: longstr,
        processData: false,
        success: function (reply) {
            console.log(reply);
        }
    });
}
```

I set the server up to reply with "ok" + the length of the post data received.  The first console log reports "106496", the second one "ok 106496".

There is no *client side* limit (eg, imposed by jquery) to how much data you can send via post.

Comment: yes that's fine. Your and mine code are no big different. But I am still not able to send more than 96 characters from ur code as well. And I fully blame servlet or webserver.

Answer (score 4):

Did you send the string as part of the URL (GET) or did you send the string as part of the POST body?

Use this to send it as POST:

```
$.post(url, {longString: veryLongString}, function(){});
```

$.post is just an alias for $.ajax (with the method param preset) => it won't make any difference which of these methods you will use.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no character limitations on a POST request. GET has limitations, but I cant recall any on POST operations.

In the above links (the ones you made reference to):

```
$.post(
"TestServletAsh?xml="+str,
function(data) {
    alert("mission successfull");   //nothing to do with it or data here in this SO question
}
);
```

sends the variable 'str' as a get parameter.

The way to send data to a POST request using jquery is

```
$.post(url, {data:'whatever you want blah blah blah'}, function(data){});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no limit in post, check your js code, you have some mistake or using the get method instead of post